# Is it possible to store Cytoscape.js layout data directly to a file format in app/web server and re-launch the same layout to minimize re-computation?

Tags: position, restore, cytoscape.js

Some of the cytoscape layout is randomize where the position is not fix every time we launch it. I understand from multiple stack overflow questions where we can save the layout data (i.e. including its position x and y) into browser local storage or session storage so that we can display the same layout using the same data.

However, the problem with local storage or session storage is good for one users. But, imagine if there are thousands of users using the same app, the server will undergo mass computation for each user to store respective data to individual browsers. Can we save the data into a file format directly into app/web server so that 1000 users will see the same layout and this reduces the computation of different data set as well.

Thank you. Would like to know the possibility to convert data into a file and store in the web/app server.

Comment: You just need to save the json to your database, are you asking how to do that?

Comment: Hi Stephan, yup! Actually my main purpose is to save and restore the state of the layout just like what has been done in this link https://codepen.io/steevokovsky/pen/yLeNJZV which is in browser level. Is there any same solution where storage is in server level?

Comment: Well, depends on your infrastructure. Basically just save to and load from a DB? Without knowing more about your project, there really is no definite answer.

Comment: Currently using React + Django + Neo4j. Should be possible?

Comment: It won't be ideal to save this data to Neo4j. I think you can just save the JSON as a file on a cloud provider like Azure or a CDN provider

Comment: By saving the JSON as a file, do we need to use Dash Cytoscape? or do you have a document on saving JSON to on premise server or cloud server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store position data. Actually, there are 2 options in my mind:

#### 1) Use [cy.json()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.json)

You can store the elements as JSON: `JSON.stringify(cy.json().elements)` and then save this JSON string.

`cy.json().elements` stores your data as shown below:

[image: cy.json().elements response]

You can restore this data easily like `cy.json({elements: JSON.parse(jsonStr))`;

#### 2) Only save position data

As you could see `cy.json().elements` is a bit big thing. Position data is just a small object like `{x: 0, y: 0}`. Additional to `position` it contains many other data. So if you only need to restore the positions, you could store them manually easily with a code like below. You can use [ele.id](https://js.cytoscape.org/#ele.id) and [node.position()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#node.position) functions.

```js
function storePositions() {
  const nodes = cy.nodes(); 
  const nodePositions = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodePositions[nodes[i].id()] = nodes[i].position();
  }
  return nodePositions;
}
```

You can also restore node positions easily. You can use [getElementById](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.getElementById) and [node.position()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#node.position) functions.

```js
function restorePositions(nodePositions) {
  const nodes = cy.nodes(); 
  const nodePositions = {};
  for (let k in nodePositions) {
    const node = cy.getElementById(k);
    if (node && node.length > 0) {
      node.position(nodePositions[k]);
    }
  }
  return nodePositions;
}
```

Comment: Hi Canbax, thank you very much for your reply. Actually, I am new to Javascript and Python. I am trying your first method actually by using setItem() and getItem(). I am able to setItem() to local storage. But, the getItem() doesn't bring back the elements in local storage. As for the second method, really appreciate your code too, and I trying to find ways to implement but not sure where to put the snippet in the code. Hope to seek your advice on the first method if you have time (= (= (=

Comment: You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem It is actually very simple. You can only store "string" in localStorage. That's a drawback. Also note that, localStorage stores settings based on URL. So if the URL is always changing, that might be a problem. Also if you open a "private tab" localStorage will be reseted as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Noted with all your points. Really appreciated (= (=

Comment: Saving just positions work, but keep in mind if your nodes are hierarchical, set the node positions for the parents first before the children. Otherwise the children might mess the positions of the parents. So in `restorePositions(nodePositions)` sort the nodes first 

`const nodes = this.cy.nodes().sort((a, b) => {
      const aDepth = a.ancestors().length;
      const bDepth = b.ancestors().length;
      return aDepth - bDepth;
    });
`